# Memo Username and Date stamp

Tags: datetime, textbox

I am new to Access and programing codes. I am building a data base where daily notes for issues can be kept. I want the end user to be able to view past records and make updates. However I do not want the to alter text previously put in the memo field containing the issue they are wanting to update. Also I am wanting to flag there new input with username and date/time.

I am try to accomplish this by inserting the following code into the AfterUpdate()

Private Sub Text0_AfterUpdate()
Me.Text0 = Me.Text0.Value & " " & UserName() & " @ " & Now()
 End Sub

I used Text0 because I am testing this code. Anyway this works in an unbound text box perfectly for flagging the new input. However when I try using this in my form with bound textboxes it fails to work. Any ideas? If I get this working I want to find a way to prevent editing on previously entered text but that is not a must.

Comment: This is a on a split form that is getting its data from a query. Also the error message I get when attempting to run the code is: The expression After Update you entered as the event property settings produced the following error: A problem occurred while Mircrosoft Access was communication with the OLE Server or ActiveX Control

Answer (score 0):

The form containing the memo textbox for update was corrupt. By copying and pasting to create a new form with everything but the textbox I was having problems with I fixed my problem. I just made a new text box in the new form.